# Show content twice - Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When you have two divs with the same id in the bootstrap tabs, is it normal for it to activate only one?

The Code

```
<ul>
   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#id1" aria-expanded="false">ID1</a><li>
   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#id1" aria-expanded="false">ID1</a><li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="id1">
        Hello 
    </div>
    <div id="2">
        Hello Again :)  
    </div>
    <div id="2">
       OMG Hello Again :)  
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I click on ID2, I only see the contents of the first div, ignoring the other one, is this normal?

Comment: Don't have duplicate ID if you really want to have duplicate identifier use name or class

Comment: How do you expect it to work? Currently your HTML doesn't even produce bootstrap tabs and the `href` both points to `id1`.

Comment: Consider it "normal" that you might get unexpected results, if you violate basic rules. That ids _must_ be unique within a document is one of them in HTML.

Comment: See this site, ilhafantasia.com.br, i use this method of tabs to separate the events, the id are the slugs of the dates, which as are repeated times if more than one event in a day

Comment: Can you not make the IDs unique on creation?

Comment: Id is something unique and are assigned to 1 element only

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is normal as you are using the same `id` for multiple divs which make the other diov extinct. You should **never** do that.

To achieve this, you can wrap your div in a parent and give it `id=2`

```
<ul>
   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#id1" aria-expanded="false">ID1</a><li>
   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#id1" aria-expanded="false">ID1</a><li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="id1">
        Hello 
    </div>
    <div id="2">
        <div> Hello Again :) </div>
        <div> OMG Hello Again :) </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't have same id for multiple elements. And if some one else is doing that then please convey this to them as well. :)

Comment: You CAN use the same ID twice, you're just not SUPPOSED to, because JavaScript methods like `document.getElementById(str)` will only return the first matching element. There are workarounds, yes, but the CORRECT solution is simply to use classes instead of IDs if repetition is expected. Don't force a square peg into a round hole.

Comment: Exactly `because JavaScript methods like document.getElementById(str) will only return the first matching element` you should not use duplicate ids. Never encourage a bad practice just because it is not doing any harm!

Comment: OT: You might be able to give two different persons the same ID card number but it would end in a mess :-)